# How to move the oldest 10 files in a directory to another directory

Tags: c#, directory

I have a C# script that is currently moving files between two directories. It moves 10 files at a time. The problem is that it is grabbing the 10 files by file name. I want it to grab the oldest 10 files each time it runs. How can I do that?

Currently, my script looks like this:

```
string[] dirsSourceDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirectory);
string[] filesSourceDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory);
string[] dirsDestinationDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(destinationDirectory);
string[] filesDestinationDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(destinationDirectory);
int filecount = Directory.GetFiles(destinationDirectory, "*.TRN", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
       FileInfo[] rgfiles = di.GetFiles();
       rgfiles[0].MoveTo(System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, rgfiles[0].Name));
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
var filesToMove = di
  .GetFiles()
  .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
  .Take(10)
  .ToArray();

foreach (var rgFile in filesToMove)
{
   rgfile.MoveTo(System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, rgfile.Name));
}
```

Comment: I think you should add `.Take(10)` in order to only move the oldest ten files.

Comment: `OrderBy` rather than `OrderByDescending` oldest first!

Comment: You could actually omit the `ToArray()`. `foreach` can directly work with the `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: @FrankPI - not sure, if GetFiles is also lazily evaluated then as files are being removed it may mutate the collection.

Comment: Good answer.  I feel compelled to point out that .Take(10) will simply return all values if there are less than 10, which avoids exceptions being thrown, unlike the for loop the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ to get the array of files, ordered from oldest to newest, like this:

```
var fileInfoArray = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(fi => fi.CreationTime).Take(10).ToArray();
```

Then you can loop through the files:

```
foreach(var file in fileInfoArray)
{
     file.MoveTo(System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, file.Name));
}
```

Comment: `OrderBy` not `OrderByDescending` you want oldest first!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the CreationTime function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try some linq

```
List<string> slist = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp").OrderBy(fn => File.GetCreationTime(fn)).ToList();
```